# breaking strict aliasing and getting away with it

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-optimization, strict-aliasing

It is well-known that optimizing C (and probably C++, too) compilers would break code that does something like this:

```
type1 foo, *pfoo;
type2_incompatible_with_type1 *pbar;
/* ... */
pfoo = &foo;
pbar = (type2_incompatible_with_type1*)pfoo;
/* ... */
while(condition){
    change_type2_value(pbar);
    /* ... */
    use_type1_value_which_should_have_changed(*pfoo);
    /* ... */
}
```

where change_type2_value looks something like this:

```
void change_type2_value(type2_incompatible_with_type1 *pbar){
    *pbar = SOME_VALUE;
}
```

The compiler might consider `pfoo` and `pbar` different pointers, although they point to the same memory location, and, therefore, will not necesserily reload the contents of `*pfoo` every time we change the value pointed to by `pbar`, even though it changes the memory pointed to by `pfoo` too.

However, if we do something like this:

```
type1 foo, *pfoo;
/* ... */
pfoo = &foo;
/* ... */
while(condition){
    change_type2_value((type2_incompatible_with_type1*)pfoo);
    /* ... */
    use_type1_value_which_should_have_changed(*pfoo);
    /* ... */
}
```

Although the dereferencing will occur *inside the `change_type2_value` function*, this still technically breaks strict aliasing as, in reality, our pointer points to a different type. However, are there any real conditions on which strict-aliasing optimization used by a real compiler could break this code too?

I think it would be a possibility if a compiler went out of the current function's scope to look at what should be happening in *another* function just to figure out if it should reload the memory pointed to by a variable that has been passed to it. Which doesn't seem too feasible to me.

Or is it possible that a real compiler can do something as nasty as assume that the function in question will *not* change the memory pointed to by our pointer if we pass it in as *cast to a pointer to an incompatible type*?

Comment: How much do you like playing with fire?  If you mess with it, you will probably get burned sooner or later — whether you're playing with fire or strict aliasing violations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly conforming? No.

Look at the following:

```
void bar(){
    int x=7;
    foo();
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

What value of `x` gets printed? It's 7. There's no legal way for `foo()` to modify `x`.

How about

```
void bar(int* x){
    *x=7;
    foo();
    printf("%d\n",*x);
}
```

All bets are off. `foo()` may have access to the address pointed to by `x` by other means. We can't say and the compiler may very well have as little to go on as we have here.
It depends where and how `foo()` is defined and how holistic the compiler is.
For example if `foo()` is `inline` etc.

Now what you've done is cast **before** passing in to `change_type2_value(.)` and since it's not strictly conformant to dereference that pointer the compiler is still conformant if it makes the assumption that `change_type2_value(.)` doesn't dereference its argument and if it is a local variable (your snippet doesn't make that clear) it absolutely can assume it hasn't changed.

**This next bit is a bad idea**

What if you replaced that call with a call to:

```
void do_secret_stuff_with_type1(type1* t1){
    type2_incompatible_with_type1* pbar = (type2_incompatible_with_type1*)pfoo;
    change_type2_value((type2_incompatible_with_type1*)pfoo);
}

type1 foo, *pfoo;
/* ... */
pfoo = &foo;
/* ... */
while(condition){
    do_secret_stuff_with_type1(pfoo); //Looks innocent, right?
    /* ... */
    use_type1_value_which_should_have_changed(*pfoo);
    /* ... */
}
```

The same goes. It's certainly making it harder for the compiler to spot what's going on. If `do_secret_stuff_with_type1()` is defined in a separate translation unit you're progressively increasing the chances you'll confound the compiler.

**End of bad idea**

However such hacking is almost certainly a dreadful idea. 
Why are you trying to do this? 
Forgetting about aliasing what are you doing that casting between incompatible types will result in a useful program?

For any real case there's almost always a solution involving accessing objects through `unsigned char*` or copying in using `memcpy()` and in some cases using a `union` that turns non-conformant programs into conformant programs.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer =) However, my question mentioned *real* compilers. Can you give an example of a compiler that will, in optimizing mode, assume that the memory pointed to by a pointer will not change after we pass this pointer to another function as casted to a pointer to an incompatible type?

Comment: @Mints97 LLVM's optimizer **does** do inter-procedural (and even inter-modular) optimization. There's a chance your code would break when compiled with `-O3 -flto` using Clang.

Comment: Mints97 I probably didn't make myself quite clear. It's possible but I'd be surprised if a compiler did anything different with your two cases. Almost all optimizing compilers erase 'redundant' local variables and will (in practice) see your two versions as equivalent. Notice my code is won't cause the bug either (in a conforming compiler).

Comment: No compiler writer who isn't being obtuse should have any trouble in your second example, provided that (as is the case there) the cast and all uses of the pointer received therefrom are performed without any intervening uses of the original object.  All a compiler would need to do is regard a cast from type T* to U* as a likely access to an object of type T except in cases where it can see that the resulting U* won't be accessed a certain way before the next use of the original pointer.  The stated purpose of the rule was to avoid forcing compilers to make "pessimistic" assumptions...

Comment: ...about aliasing when there's no reason to expect it.  If the authors of the Standard actually intended compilers to regard aliasing as impossible even when it's obvious, using an example where a compiler would have no reason to expect aliasing would have been disingenuous.  I think it's far more likely that the authors of the Standard thought that certain patterns of aliasing were sufficiently obvious that compiler writers didn't need to be ordered to support them.

Comment: @supercat:  That's a bizarre position to take when writing a standard. Though the C Standards are far from clear and do read like a series of design notes rather than closed definitions.

Comment: @DanAllen: Read the C89 rationale's comments about implementation limits.  The authors of the Standard knew they couldn't accurately describe everything an implementation could do, but expected compiler writers to go beyond the Standard's requirements when it made sense to do so.  Consider also that the authors of the Standard wanted to allow that, to the extent possible, any code which worked and achieved a certain level of performance on a given implementation should continue to work with that same level of performance on a C89 implementation for the same platform.  If there is some code...

Comment: ...which requires the ability to use type punning via pointers, but there is other code which can only meet performance requirements on a compiler that does type-based aliasing, there is no way to specify an implementation that will work with both, unless the Standard is interpreted as saying that compilers are allowed to do type-based aliasing but is also allowed to make type punning useful.  If one reads the rationale for promoting short unsigned values to signed int, it's clear that the authors of the Standard recognized that there were some behaviors that were common...

Comment: ...to the majority of implementations and were useful, but the authors of the Standard--perhaps to ensure acceptance from makers of obscure architectures--declined to describe "optional" behaviors which quality implementations should support when practical, but could be omitted on implementations where they would be impractical.

Comment: A standard for fasteners should guarantee that every compliant class X nut will work with every compliant class X bolt, every class Y nut with every class Y bolt, etc. such that someone with a class X nut could identify bolts with which it will work by asking "Is it a class X bolt?"  The C89 document, however, cannot be used in such a fashion.  There is no guarantee that even strictly-conforming programs will run on every implementation without UB (indeed, one could have a pair of implementations such that every program would invoke UB on at least one of them).  If the maintainers of...

Comment: ...the C Standard would accept the notion that different implementations have natural abilities, they *could* define a means by which programs could specify special requirements, and require that all conforming implementations must either honor all stated requirements or identify at least one they do not meet.  That would in turn make it possible to define a large class of "selectively-conforming" programs which would be guaranteed not to invoke UB on any implementation which meets all specified requirements, and thus make the "Standard" usable as an actual standard.